# C# Why memory leak in my sample code?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WeakReference wfRaiser;
        WeakReference wfSubscriber;

        var before = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

        //region 1: scope of raiser
        {
            var raiser = new Raiser();
            wfRaiser = new WeakReference(raiser);
            //region 2: scope of subscriber
            {
                var subscriber = new Subscriber();
                wfSubscriber = new WeakReference(subscriber);
                raiser.ValueChanged += subscriber.HandlingMethod;
            }

            raiser.SetValue(153);
        }

        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        GC.Collect();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        var after = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

        Console.WriteLine($"Is raiser alive? {wfRaiser.IsAlive}\n" +
                          $"Is subscriber alive? {wfSubscriber.IsAlive}\n" +
                          "Memory size (bytes):\n" +
                          $"- before : {before} \n" +
                          $"- after : {after}\n" +
                          $"=> Leak: {after - before}");
    }
}

public class Raiser
{
    public event EventHandler<int> ValueChanged;
    public void SetValue(int value) => ValueChanged?.Invoke(this, value);
}

public class Subscriber
{
    private readonly double[] MyData = new double[9999];
    public void HandlingMethod(object sender, int value) => Console.WriteLine($"Value changed: {value}");
}
```

I don't understand the reason of memory leak in this code.
I know that the **raiser** keeps reference to **subscriber** (via event handler) even out of region 2. However, I think both of them should be released after region 1 when **raiser** is collected by GC.

As the Weak References show, both raiser and subscriber are released. Then why there is still memory leak?

I build my code in Release mode with Code optimization enabled.
This is my output:

```
Value changed: 153
Is raiser alive? False
Is subscriber alive? False
Memory size (bytes):
- before : 21960
- after : 29520
=> Leak: 7560
```

Comment: Perhaps the memory wfRaiser and wfSubscriber use may account for some of the memory leak?

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath I don't think so. Even when I removed those weak references, the result was still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values are just fixed cost overheads of other things that are created in the background, if you run the test twice in in your program you will have a 0 byte change for the 2nd and any other subsequent runs.

Running a memory profiler on the code found the bulk of the 7590 is internal `string` and `char[]` buffers of the `TextWriter` that `Console.WriteLine()` uses internally.

Here is a tweaked version of your test that returns 0 for the 2nd test run on my machine.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunTest();
        RunTest();
    }

    private static void RunTest()
    {
        //WeakReference wfRaiser;
        //WeakReference wfSubscriber;

        var before = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

        //region 1: scope of raiser
        {
            var raiser = new Raiser();
            //wfRaiser = new WeakReference(raiser);
            //region 2: scope of subscriber
            {
                var subscriber = new Subscriber();
                //wfSubscriber = new WeakReference(subscriber);
                raiser.ValueChanged += subscriber.HandlingMethod;
            }

            raiser.SetValue(153);
        }

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();

        var after = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

        Console.WriteLine(//$"Is raiser alive? {wfRaiser.IsAlive}\n" +
                          //$"Is subscriber alive? {wfSubscriber.IsAlive}\n" +
                          "Memory size (bytes):\n" +
                          $"- before : {before} \n" +
                          $"- after : {after}\n" +
                          $"=> Leak: {after - before}");
    }
}

public class Raiser
{
    public event EventHandler<int> ValueChanged;
    public void SetValue(int value) => ValueChanged?.Invoke(this, value);
}

public class Subscriber
{
    private readonly double[] MyData = new double[9999];
    public void HandlingMethod(object sender, int value) => Console.WriteLine($"Value changed: {value}");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You are right. When extracted the code into a method and called it many times, only the first run produced that  _memory leak_, the following runs shown 24 bytes change.

Comment: replace your `Thread.Sleep`s with `GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); GC.Collect();` and get rid of the two weak refrence objects and you will get 0 for runs after the first one.